# How to read rtc driver data (dev/rtc0) from embedded c application?

Tags: linux, bash, embedded

I'm basically trying to read the output of the below command in my c application.

```
timedatectl
```

so basically I wanted to read the RTC time through my application so for the same reason I was trying to read the output of the above command in my application.

O is there any other way to read the time from the RTC by using

```
/dev/rtc0
```

Any help will be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want raw access to control `/dev/rtc0` then you need to use the `ioctl` call after opening the file (as per [manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/rtc.4.html)), e.g.

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/rtc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int rtc_fd = open("/dev/rtc0", O_RDONLY);
    if (rtc_fd < 0)
    {
        perror("");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    struct rtc_time read_time;

    if (ioctl(rtc_fd, RTC_RD_TIME, &read_time) < 0)
    {
        close(rtc_fd);
        perror("");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    close(rtc_fd);

    printf("RTC Time is: %s\n", asctime((struct tm*)&read_time));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```